# What List<? super Object> mean in java?

Tags: java, generics

From javadoc we know:Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.The `List<? super Object>` means what?

Comment: [Mightbe Helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java check this, it explains what you are asking

Comment: Logically `List<? super Object>` must mean the same as `List<Object>` (if it also behaves the same in all situation I don’t guarantee immediately).

Comment: @jpganz18 thank you,the question contains more details.